# Getting force close when trying to parse JSON Object Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I have created REST web service using jersey which returns JSON response. JSON response returned by web service is as follow-

```
{
  "Disease": "Bacterial_blight",
  "Control": "Foliar sprays of streptocycline sulphate @ 0.5 gm/land copper-oxychlode @ 3 g / l of water as and when symptoms seen."
}
```

I have made Android app activity for demo purpose which contains one radio button, one Edit text box and one Button to submit the parameters to REST web service. But Problem is I'm getting force close when I try to click on Submit Button.

This is the actual android activity class code-

```
package com.doitgeek.agroadvisorysystem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class DiseaseResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView diseaseTV;
    public TextView controlMechanismTV;
    public EditText etSymptom;
    public RadioButton rbL;
    public Button btnSubmit;
    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disease_result);

        diseaseTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.diseaseTV);
        controlMechanismTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.controlMechanismTV);
        etSymptom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSymptom);
        rbL = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbL1);
        btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    }

    public void onClickSubmit(View view) {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String affectedPart = rbL.getText().toString();
        String symptom = etSymptom.getText().toString();
        params.put("affectedPart", affectedPart);
        params.put("symptom", symptom);
        invokeWS(params);
    }

    /* Invocation of RESTful WS */
    public void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
        dialog.show();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://192.168.0.100:8080/AgroAdvisorySystem/webapi/disease_prediction/result", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                dialog.hide();
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)new JSONTokener(response.toString()).nextValue();
                    JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("Disease");
                    String disease = obj2.toString();
                    /*JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String disease = obj.getJSONObject("Disease").toString();*/
                    diseaseTV.setText(disease);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurred [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                dialog.hide();
                if(statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occurred! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I didn't find working solution till now that is why I am posting this as question.

Answer (score 0):

So, what`s the Exception record?

It seems that the problem is in:

`JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("Disease");`

where the item `Disease` is no longer a `JSONObject`.

Try `obj.getSyting("Disease")`